Need to change 300 sheet names as the first cell value in their respective sheet
I have over 300 sheets whose name needs to be changed as the first cell (A1).
I initially tried to write code from the internet
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

ActiveSheet.Name = Range("A1")

End Sub

It worked for only one sheet. I want to apply it to all.
Sub vba_loop_sheets()

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

ActiveSheet.Name = Range("A1")

End Sub

So I tried this but it didnt work. Please help

You can use the ws variable to do it all in one shot, without worrying about which sheet is active.
You will want to test for an empty cell and if the worksheet name already existing first tho, or it will error.
Sub vba_loop_sheets()
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
  If Not ws.Range("A1").Value = "" And Not WorksheetExists(ws.Range("A1").Value) Then
    ws.Name = ws.Range("A1").Value
  Else
    Debug.Print ws.Range("A1").Value & " is already used"
  End If
Next

End Sub

Function WorksheetExists(shtName As String, Optional wb As Workbook) As Boolean
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    On Error Resume Next
    Set sht = wb.Worksheets(shtName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    WorksheetExists = Not sht Is Nothing
End Function


Welcome to the board.
In a normal module paste and run this code. Note - this assumes all the values in A1 of each sheet can be used as valid sheet names, there's no duplicates, etc.
Sub ChangeSheetNames()

    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
    'ThisWorkbook means the workbook containing this code.
    For Each wrkSht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        wrkSht.Name = wrkSht.Range("A1")
    Next wrkSht

End Sub

